# regex split string into consecutive letter pairs (not recurring)

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm struggling to figure out how to generate a series of consecutive letter/character pairs from a string, incrementing over each letter. i.e. `"FOOBARBAZ"` should find:

```
[ "FO", "OO", "OB", "BA", "AR", "RB", "BA", "AZ" ]
```

And `FRANCE`
becomes

```
["FR", "RA", "AN", "NC", "CE"]
```

All I can find on stackoverflow are questions of finding successive pairs (`"FRANCE" => [FR, AN, CE]`) or repeating `aabbb => [aa, bbb]`, not iterative.

My regex-fu is not so strong and I feel like this could possibly be a lookahead but I'm sure how to capture the pairs. I don't think I have recursion `(?R)` available (SNOWFLAKE SQL Regex)

EDIT: It looks like snowflake sql regex supports POSIX basic and extended, and as such lookaheads/behinds don't seem to be supported

Comment: Sorry that's the output I'd like to generate, so I'd like to find those groups of pairs: match1: FR, match2: RA, match3: AN etc.

Comment: It would cut out a few steps in the SQL, as now it needs to regex_split (normal split doesn't split all chars; snowflake issue), and then flatten to a table and then do a LEAD to fetch the next letter in the sequence. If I could just skip it all and use regex that would improve the UDF performance which is becoming an issue

Comment: I understand Snowflake permits the construction of a [User-defined function (UDF)](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting_started_with_user_defined_sql_functions/index.html#0) for which Javascript and Java are supported. Both those languages' regex engines support lookaheads. Is use of a UDF for your application a possibility? [Here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007PkpgcSAB/regex-written-inside-javascript-udf-behaves-differently) is a discussion that may be relevant.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried an implementation in a Javascript UDF but I'd like a native SQL UDF implementation if possible to try to improve performance

Comment: SQL Only: `WITH cte AS (
   SELECT 'FRANCE' AS col
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'FOOBARBAZ'
)
SELECT col,
       ARRAY_AGG(s.this[index]::TEXT || s.this[index+1]::TEXT)
FROM cte,
LATERAL FLATTEN(REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL(col, '(.)')) AS s(v)
GROUP BY col;` https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBa55.png

Comment: @JordanWhitfield I had posted a solution that should have worked. Does it not?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Snowflake SQL, but it seems that [`REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all) accepts a `position` argument from which it will start to find matches.

That means you can find the matches at odd indices (the default value is `1`):

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL("FRANCE", "..")     -- Probably ["FR", "AN", "CE"]
```

...then at even indices:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL("FRANCE", "..", 2)  -- Probably ["RA", "NC"]
```

...and finally merge them to get the final result.

This holds even if your sliding window is longer: You just have to repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

After posting my answer I became aware that Snowflake SQL's regex engine does not support lookaheads, on which my answer relies. Evidently, a Javascript UDF could be employed to gain access to Javascript's regex engine, which does support lookaheads, but the OP has stated in a comment on the question that performance is unsatisfactory with that option. I will leave my answer up, however, in part to show how the question could be answered in situations where the regex engine supports lookaheads.

---

You can match

```
(?=(..))
```

in which case capture group 1 will hold one of the desired two-character strings.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4vY5H/1)

`(?=(..))` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the next two characters must be present and the string they comprise is to be saved to capture group 1.

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect, if not for the fact that Snowflake (POSIX) regex doesn't seem to support lookaheads. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does allow you to reference a capture group so you could do

```
set str = 'FOOBARBAZ';
select regexp_substr_all(regexp_replace($str,'(.)','\\1\\1'),'..',2);
```

The basic idea is: repeat every letter in the string --> extract all matches by starting at the second position to automatically skip first and last letter